# 'office' or 'the office' in this context?

Tags: grammar

Here are my constructions:

> 1. Administration **of office** network infrastructure and implementation
>      of new services
> 2. Administration **of the office** network infrastructure and
>      implementation of new services

So my question is, should I use 'the office' or 'office'?

P.S.
This is for use in a bullet-point list.

Comment: Could we have more context, please? Is this for use in a bullet-point list?

Comment: This is for use in a bullet-point list.

Comment: Can you explain why you're thinking about putting an article before ***office***, but not before ***implementation*** or ***new**?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of an item in a bullet-point list, the first construction, without 'the', is fine. It seems that you're referring to office network infrastructure in general, which may or may not be for a single office, and as such, you don't need the definite article 'the' before it.

Comment: I agree. ,,,,,,,,,,,,,